# ckeditor - how to add css class to input element in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm  editing a plugin under CKEditor, `link.js` under link plugin. I added a text input field and trying to assign a css class to input but can't do it. This is my code I added.

```
{
    type : 'text',
    class: 'myClassName',
    label : 'myInputLabel'
}
```

I also tried `className`, `inputClass`, `inputStyle` instead of `class` but none of them worked.

I need to have something like this

```
<input class="cke_dialog_ui_input_text myClassName" type="text" aria-labelledby="cke_102_label">
```

## Workaround using jQuery

Seems CKEditor doesn't let you assign className directly to input element but it assigns it to input element's third level parent div

```
<div class='cke_dialog_ui_text myClassName'>
   <div>
      <div>
         <input class='cke_dialog_ui_input_text'>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**What I did to make it work**

```
{
    type : 'text',
    className : 'myClassName',
    label : 'myInputLabel',
    onLoad : function () {
        var myid = this.getElement().getId();
        var that = this;
        var thatobj = $("#" + myid);
        var obj = $(".cke_dialog_ui_input_text", thatobj);

        //Have fun with your "obj" text input
        //variable "that" is good to have because you may need it inside of jQuery plugins like that.getDialog().setValueOf('info', 'url', 'blahblah');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`className` should work for you [according to the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.uiElement-property-className). Double-check your code. Otherwise try to mess with your field on `dialogDefinition` event. See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374).

Comment: seems CKEditor does not assign defined class name to input but to it's third wrapper div. edited my question for workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  type: 'text',
  label: 'My text input',
  onLoad : function () {
    this.getInputElement().$.classList.add('class-for-my-input');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be simplified to `this.getInputElement().addClass('my-class')`