# ckeditor image dialog size

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have configured my own custom image repository using ckeditor image plugin. 
Now i want to change the size of image dialog. I have checked a lot but found properties for changing height and width of file browser and ckeditor itself only.
How could i change the size of image dialog that appears on oncliking the image icon in ckeditor toolbar.

Here is my code:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    config.height = '350px';
    //config.width = '1000px';
    config.uiColor = '#d6d6d6';
    config.fullPage = true;
    config.extraPlugins = 'importdoc,docprops';
    config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'jcrPage';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'jcrPage';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'imageUpload';
    config.filebrowserWindowHeight = 500;
    config.filebrowserWindowWidth = 500;
    config.filebrowserImageWindowWidth = 700;
    config.filebrowserImageWindowHeight = 700;
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode'] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection'] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
    ];
    config.removePlugins = 'flash, iframe, templates, div, source, smiley, save, newpage';
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of the dialog is controlled by 4 properties: [`width`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition-property-width), [`height`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition-property-height), [`minWidth`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition-property-minWidth), [`minHeight`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition-property-minHeight).

And to know how to customize a definition of an existing dialog, please refer to my previous answer: [How do I customize a ckeditor 4.2 builtin plugin like links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374)

Comment: Thanks it worked with some help of  this link:-
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows-section-6