# How to disable Headers in table properties for CkEditor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

How can I disable headers in table properties for CKEditor, like that of rows and columns in the image given below.

[image]

I am working on CKEditor version 3.0 in an asp.net web application, I tried to make some changes in *table.js* (inside the plugins-->table folder) but didn't get the desired output.

Comment: Check my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374 You got to use `dialogDefinition` event.

Comment: Thanx @oleq for your solution,however i made few changes in _ckeditor.js_ and it worked for me. :)

Comment: @oleq if you post an answer which solves this problem(not a generalized solution like your previous answer) then I would like to mark it as right answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dialogDefinition` event ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/cX9gk/)):

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( evt ) {
    var dialog = evt.data;

    if ( dialog.name == 'table' ) {
        // Get dialog definition.
        var def = evt.data.definition;

        def.onShow = function() {
            var select = this.getContentElement( 'info', 'selHeaders' );
            select.disable();                
        }        
    }    
} );
```

Comment: Its giving an error, **CKEDITOR is undefined** when i paste your code in javascript,I think CKEDITOR dose't load till that time...do you have any idea what to do about it?

Comment: @SidM Did you read the [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load)?

Comment: still it dose't work..Don't know why? 

although your solution seems to be fine but why it isn't working for me?

i just pasted this on source of ckeditor
`<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    text</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>` and that dropdown was still enabled :(

Honestly you deserve an upvote or many upvotes i should say but still it dose't works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, it works for me.

```
window.CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        ev.editor.getCommand( 'table' ).allowedContent = "table{width,height}[align,border,cellpadding,cellspacing,summary];caption tbody thead tfoot;th td tr;table[id,dir](*){*}";
        if (dialogName == "table" || dialogName == "tableProperties") {
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents("info");            
            infoTab.get("txtWidth")["default"] = "";
            infoTab.get("txtCellSpace")["default"] = "";
            infoTab.get("txtCellPad")["default"] = "";
            infoTab.get("txtBorder")["default"] = "";

            infoTab.get("selHeaders")["items"].pop();
            infoTab.get("selHeaders")["items"].pop();

            var advancedTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'advanced' );
            advancedTab.remove( 'advCSSClasses' );
        }
    });
```

Comment: `if (dialogName == "table" && dialogName == "tableProperties") {`
How should this work? :-D

Comment: @Wolfgang, yeah you are right. That condition was wrong. I have corrected it now. Thanks for highlighting it.