# How to add title attribute at CKEditor images

Tags: image, ckeditor

Is there a way to add the title attibute to CKEditor images? I'm using v4.1.2 and CKEditor is removing it automatically each time it's added from the HTML source view. I haven't found anything about this!

Comment: That's advanced content filtering that removes it from source. Adjust your ACF config to allow it :) Other than that, no idea at all.

Comment: can i know how u did this i really can't understand i want to add download="" attribute in <a href=""> how u did this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to define [`config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[title]'`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) if you want `title` attribute to be accepted into editor contents (see: [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've already used `config.extraAllowedContent` to add some tags and attributes before this, but I was wondering if it's possible to add it from the `Image` dialog, but it seems not possible...

Comment: You got to add an extra field to Image dialog with `allowedContent` to do this. It's not that hard at all: see my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374

Answer (score 0):

I have ultimate solution for this issue..

1) Open this file: ckeditor\plugins\image2\plugin.js
At the line number 343 (in my case) add below code 
title: this.data.alt 
just below "alt: this.data.alt," and enjoy..