# how to add attribute to tags in CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I need that my link will have attribute `vfoto='advert'`.

For example:

```
<a href='#' class='link' vfoto='advert'><img src='/pick.png'/></a>
```

How to realize that? What files to edit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience width CKEDITOR, but accordint to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671519/how-to-add-title-attribute-at-ckeditor-images) and [this documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) you need to allow the attribute you want to add in the `config`.

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[vfoto]';
```

Hope that helps, see ya :)