# How to automatically set title to be the same as alt for img tag when using ckeditor with image2 plugin?

Tags: javascript, image, ckeditor, title

I want to be able to set the title tag to the final image in ckeditor using image2 plugin. When I use the image2 plugin the title tag disapears.

I have a fully operational ckeditor on my page, but would like to have a title tag that is automatically set when image is inserted to the alt given in the image2 dialog. I searched for hours for a solution but noone seems to have the same problem, so i decided to ask if anyone knows a solution for it.

I have tried using the CKEDITOR.replace method to change it on instanceReady:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('element_id',{
  on: {
       instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    img: function( el ) {
                       el.attributes.title = el.attributes.alt;
                    }
                }
            });            
        }
    }
});
```

but that didn't work..

tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330124

that didn't work either

I have `config.extraAllowedContent` set to `'*(*);*{*}'` in config.js for ckeditor that should allow all tags and attributes.

Comment: So turns out i already solved it, but had to clear cahce for chrome, beacause it would never update otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Do as https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330124 and maybe you have to tweak some more in image2 
plugin.js but after that you have to clear cahce for the browser beacause otherwise it'll never update.