# Resize dialogs in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

after I manually delete some unneccessary options on image dialog, I get this dialog:

[image]

Question: How do I resize this dialog, to fit nicely URL option???

Comment: How did you delete those options? Via `dialogDefinition` event like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374 ?

Comment: like this - http://pastebin.com/ZLF3iTtc