# Custom button on CKEditor's File Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

CKeditor has a built-in  File Browse and Upload. It can be integrated with many external plugins including CKFinder or even KCFinder (free alternative).

[image]

How can I add a custom button on the existing default panel? (For example, a compress image button under preview which would call my an external PHP script).

Comment: compressing it in JS would be quicker and more satisfying for the user.

Comment: Well, you could also show me how. I used PHP's GD Library to compress image files so that if the user changes width and height in the dialog box, it should create an actual file like that on the server - for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I read code written in another answer, but still wasn't clear and had to dive into documentation. I finally managed to settle for this fix, didn't know where to add it, so I put it into my $(document).ready() function. Open to suggestions on a better place to put it but it works:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( evt ) {
    var dialog = evt.data;
    if ( dialog.name == 'image' ) {
        // Get dialog we want
        var def = evt.data.definition;

        //Get The Desired Tab Element
        var infoTab = def.getContents( 'info' );

        //Add Our Button
        infoTab.add( {
            type: 'button',
            id: 'buttonId',
            label: 'Compress Image',
            title: 'My title',
            onClick: function() {
                //Here define what to do when button is clicked.
                //In my case, I traverse and get the inputs (dirty way).
                  var url = $(".cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child .cke_dialog_ui_text .cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content .cke_dialog_ui_input_text .cke_dialog_ui_input_text").eq(0).val();
                  var width = $(".cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child .cke_dialog_ui_text .cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content .cke_dialog_ui_input_text .cke_dialog_ui_input_text").eq(2).val();
                  var height = $(".cke_dialog_ui_vbox_child .cke_dialog_ui_text .cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content .cke_dialog_ui_input_text .cke_dialog_ui_input_text").eq(3).val();

                //Then I perform an ajax call to a Php file                             
                  $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'path/to/compress.php',
                    data: { 
                        url: url,
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(output) {
                        alert(output);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
} );
```

EDIT:

So, in the end, I created a separate file called KCFinderHelper.js which I import and use wherever I need it. (my final code is actually much longer as I added many more functions and buttons)

Comment: How do you get the dialog to update and show preview of new image file?

Comment: Just update the URL field with the link path to the newly created file using Jquery after you successfully compress it.

Comment: Could be something like this(using SetValueOf - from CKeditor), I encode the URI because some of my file paths have spaces (likewise decode it before sending to PHP): 

`var theDialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
theDialog.setValueOf('info','txtUrl',encodeURI('path/to/new/file.jpg'));`

Answer (score 0):

Extend the dialog on `dialogDefinition` event. See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133800/how-do-i-customize-a-ckeditor-4-2-builtin-plugin-like-links/18142374#18142374) to know more. Also see the [existing implementation](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/dc8dccc5eb8c22b69a1061ea130cf090da4e3ebf/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js#L437) of the Image dialog to find out how the definition looks like.

Comment: Which file I'm i supposed to modify? Should I do that in config.js?